# Reading lines from stdout with fgets()

Tags: c, file, stdout

After reading documentation, Stack answers and C standard, I still seem not to get something.

I wanted to redirect the output to the certain file and then compare the output with the predicted result; I'm going to indicate the main issue using comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SEQ 120

void printer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d0 ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            printf("0%d ", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void check_string() {
    FILE* pointer = freopen("./check_str_out", "w", stdout);

    char* storage = malloc(MAX_SEQ);
    char* test_results[] = {"00 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n", "10 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n",
    "20 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n", "30 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n", "40 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n", "\n"};
    int counter = 0;
    printer();

    freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
    FILE* output = fopen("./check_str_out", "r");  //It was added in the new version
    printf("sth\n");
    while (fgets(storage, MAX_SEQ, output)) {  //previous: while (fgets(storage, MAX_SEQ, pointer))
        printf("sth2\n");
        printf("count: %d, stor: %s, test: %s, comp: %d\n", counter, storage, test_results[counter], strcmp(storage, test_results[counter])); //E) strcmp(storage, test_results[counter++])
        counter++; 
    }
    free(storage);
    fclose(output);

}

int main(void) {
    check_string();
    return 0;
}
```

The question is: why did this code not work when I used `pointer`? Why did I have to open the file? Now everything is correct. I've tested also with:

```
FILE* pointer = freopen("./check_str_out", "w+", stdout);
```

in order to check, whether it is a matter of mode, but it didn't work.

For clarity: it doesn't print the while loop if there is pointer in fgets() used, it doesn't enter it.

EDIT:
From [this description](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.4) I can't see the `fclose()` of the file opened by `freopen()`, however it looks like the stream has been closed. What is the cause of that?

Comment: This shouldn't compile since you haven't declared `res`. Also, check the result of all calls, like the return values from your `freopen` calls.

Comment: Alright, I forgot to delete res from this code, I'll edit, thank you

Comment: If I ddidn't open the file with fopen(), fgets() for `pointer` returned NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing `test_results` out of bounds so your program has [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
void printer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d0 ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            printf("0%d ", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");         // this line makes it print 6 lines to the file
}
```

And in your `while` loop `counter` will reach `5` and `test_results[5]` is out of bounds.

Always test the return value from functions that may fail, like `freopen`, and also make sure that you're not running out of bounds when depending on external data (like your data file, that may get  corrupted for other reasons).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SEQ 120

void printer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d0 ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            printf("0%d ", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n"); // this extra line doesn't matter if you check bounds later
}

void check_string() {
    if (freopen("./check_str_out", "w", stdout)==NULL) {
        perror("./check_str_out");
        return;
    }

    char* storage = malloc(MAX_SEQ);
    if (storage == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return;
    }

    char* test_results[] = {"00 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n",
                            "10 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n",
                            "20 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n",
                            "30 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n",
                            "40 00 01 02 03 04 05 \n"};
    int counter = 0;
    printer();

    if (freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout) == NULL) {
        perror("/dev/tty");
        return;
    }

    FILE* output = fopen("./check_str_out", "r");
    if(output == NULL) {
        perror("./check_str_out");
        return;
    }

    while (counter < sizeof test_results / sizeof *test_results &&
           fgets(storage, MAX_SEQ, output))
    {
        printf("count: %d, stor: %s, test: %s, comp: %d\n", counter,
               storage, test_results[counter],
               strcmp(storage, test_results[counter]));
        counter++; 
    }
    free(storage);
    fclose(output);
}

int main(void) {
    check_string();
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding `pointer`:
`pointer == stdout` throughout the whole program after `FILE* pointer = freopen("./check_str_out", "w", stdout);`. You can't *read* from `stdout`. It's write-only.

"*I can't seen the `fclose()` of the file opened by `freopen()`, however it looks like the stream has been closed. What is the cause of that?*" - `stdout` is closed automatically when the program terminates.

Comment: Ted, but it doesn't print anything with pointer. It should segfault when it encounters the additional newline, not return NULL at the first line. However, I will fix test_results, because this is something I have noticed a moment ago, too (still didn't work with pointer)

Comment: @Funny "_It should segfault when it encounters the additional newline_" - It is free to do whatever it likes. The program has undefined behavior

Comment: Thank you for your commitment, but I'm afraid that it isn't the issue in that case, I'll add an additional question to edit.

Comment: @Funny Ok, I added a comment about that to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now it's much clearer. However, now I'm wondering, what *is* the `pointer`, beside that it's a pointer. `The freopen function returns a null pointer if the open operation fails. Otherwise, freopen returns the value of stream.` - what is the **value of that stream**, of stdout? I've tried to `printf("%p\n", pointer);`, although `p` is rather for voids, but I got segfault. I'm trying to fully understand that, even trying to visualize what should I expect.

Comment: @Funny You're welcome! If `freopen` succeeds it'll return a pointer (`stdout` is a pointer too) pointing at the same `FILE` as `stdout`.